# DialogResult Filter multiple extensions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

I want to display an open file dialog and filter both **.csv** and **.txt** files. I've set the filter accordingly but it's only showing .csv files.

**Here's my code:**

```
var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

dialog.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
bool? isOK = dialog.ShowDialog();

if (isOK == true)
{
    ImportFilePath = dialog.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show multiple file types at the same time, you should include them in a single filter:

```
dialog.Filter = "Plain text files (*.csv;*.txt)|*.csv;*.txt";
```

Otherwise the user will have to select the type of file in the bottom Combobox of the dialog.

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) has some useful examples of this.